# ¿Como cerrar ventana del navegador cuando selenium marque error de conexion?

Tags: c#, selenium

cuando ejecuto esta linea de codigo el navegador se abre automaticamente en modo oculto

```
Driver = new ChromeDriver(Service, Opciones)
{
    Url = UrlTextBox.Text
};
```

hasta aqui todo bien, el problema viene cuando al ejecutar esa linea de codigo y se va el internet, el navegador queda abierto en el administrador de tareas y no se puede cerrar a menos que lo cierres por medio del administrador de tareas, ¿Como puedo cerrar la vantana abierta cuando se vaya el internet? PD. el driver automaticamente cuando salta el error se pone en null

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar lo siguiente

```
if (driver != null) {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Para el administrador de tareas este comando en cmd y igual puedes ejecutarlo en java:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412976/close-chrome-from-bat-file